# Listing out JSON items dynamically in HTML using JS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working in 'for in' loop. In that I'm listing out JSON items dynamically in html. but what happens is, it prints over and over even if i give break tag. but i get all items in console. please help.

```
var key, i=0;
var x = document.getElementById("list1");   
for (var key in add) {
    if (add.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        x.innerHTML='<div class="item txt1">'+add.item[i].name+'</div><br/>' ;
        i++;            
        console.log(add.item[i].name);
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use a different 'i' var, You can simply use key inplace of i, as in line for (var key in add),, key is index itself.. 2) use x.innerHTML+=

Comment: This line "x.innerHTML='<div class="item txt1">'+add.item[i].name+'</div><br/>' ;" keep add in single place.So you need to create a string first then add that to innerHtml. KTO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget get the current html code of x element.

```
var key, i=0;
var x = document.getElementById("list1");   
for (var key in add) {
    if (add.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        x.innerHTML = x.innerHTML + '<div class="item txt1">'+add.item[i].name+'</div><br/>' ;
        i++;            
        console.log(add.item[i].name);
    } else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`console.log()` logs data **only** to the console ! If you want to write to the html document you have to use `document.write` or `document.writeln()`! For more information you can visit [W3C schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp).

Comment: I'm using innerHTML and i get last value as the loop ends in HTML

Comment: You have to get the current html as @oguzhancerit says!